Using Graphql+AppSync with a graph database (Neptune) - n+1 problem still an issue?
Going straight to the point: we are using Graphql (with/in AppSync), using a Neptune database (graph database) as source of data.
A couple of questions rose from some tests and cross conversations that happened.

Being a graph database,  is federation still a benefit? I ask this cause with a graph, you don't really need to fire off multiple queries - one query can transverse the graph for whatever the query asked for

following up on that, is the n+1 problem still valid? We are just sending the request from AppSync to Neptune using a lambda of our own that just parses the query and builds up the gremlin query.


It is my understanding that this will fire one instance of the query and the resolver (from AppSync side) just sends the query as a whole.

performance wise, should we have a federation of sorts in AppSync itself? Feels weird cause graph database is meant to just deliver whatever you asked in one go, taking into account the edges exists

how to improve performance on One vertex having Tons of linked vertices? As in having a Store Vertex with items vertices (millions).


Thanks my friends

I think a lot of these considerations were addressed in the Neptune GraphQL utility for AppSync.  Have you reviewed this before?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/tools-graphql.html
https://github.com/aws/amazon-neptune-for-graphql
